# How to add a custom frame at the top bar and in the footer area of Storefront

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, storefront

I would like to add a thin custom frame at the very top and very end of my website.

This is for my Woocommerce Webshop. I am using the Storefront theme. The frame should be responsive to any screen.
Then frame is a jpeg file (of course I can convert it to any other image file if needed).

Comment: Share us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I installed a plugin called Top Bar, uploaded the image to my webspace and then inserted this simple code to make it appear on the Top Bar: 
`<p><span style="background-color: #ffffff00;"><img src="https://www.example-domain.com/images/image.jpg" alt="" width="2413" height="36" /></span></p>`

I am unable to get transparent background/use the websites background. The background of the Top Bar plugin will be used and I cannot make it transparent. Also problem #2 is that the image is a pattern and it should be repeated to fill the width of the screen (that's why it should be responsive).

Comment: Don't know how to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should create a child theme for storefront so you can customize your theme without the need of those plugins.
Read here how to setup your child theme : 
     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/

Second step is to add html to your header.php and footer.php

```
<div class="myrepeatableimg"></div>
```

Add some css to your style.css file or to the wordpress customizer.

```
.myrepeatableimg{
 width: 100%; 
 height:50px; 
 background-repeat:repeat;
 background-image: url('https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/folk-pattern.png'); }
```

```css
.myrepeatableimg{
width:100%; height:100px;
background-image: url('https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/folk-pattern.png'); 
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="myrepeatableimg"></div>
```